# Is it possible to mine cryptocurrency on a VM?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I would like to know if is there possible to mine cryptocurrency XMT on a Google Cloud VM?

Thanks you.

Comment: Read their terms of service.

Comment: Even if they permitted it, it wouldn't be cost effective.

Answer (score 2):

Mining cryptocurrency is not allowed without Google's prior written approval as per [Google Cloud Platform Terms of Service](https://cloud.google.com/terms):

```
3.3 Restrictions. Customer will not, and will not allow 
End Users [...] (iv) to engage in cryptocurrency mining 
without Google's prior written approval;
```